# Unexpected DynamoDB streams batching behavior

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have created DynamoDB with stream enabled and given Batch window =60 sec and batch size=100 so that my Lambda will wait 60 seconds to trigger with all items in single Lambda.

I have added 7 items into DynamoDB and Lambda triggered after 60 seconds only but at 60 seconds it triggered three lambdas with 2 items,2 items,4 items in respective lambdas event.

What could be the issue?

[image: dynamostream configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you have multiple partitions in DynamoDB. Each will initiate its own lambda invocations.

If your table is in On Demand mode then it starts with four partitions. Your updates touched three of them.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. Yes this is the answer and do you have any idea how much these partitions can extend ? And also these lambdas trigger asyncronous or synchronous

Comment: This blog post provides a lot of details about how all of this works: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-perform-ordered-data-replication-between-applications-by-using-amazon-dynamodb-streams/